# Incentives for support agent to provide feedback

Tags: gamification, incentives

I am exploring ways support agents could be encouraged to provide feedback to the system about whether a suggested solution (e.g. user has to delete cookies from browser) solved the problem or not. Adding a mechanism to submit "yes, it works/no, it doesn't work" is quite simple. What I am not convinced about is that agents will be pushing the buttons. There are some products that introduced gamification aspects into the support systems (e.g. http://freshdesk.com/gamification-of-support-help-desk/). I wonder if anyone tried any kind of free incentive mechanisms for support agents and what worked. Things that come to mind are different badges and statuses assigned to agents based on number of submitted answers.

Comment: I suggest reading *Reality is Broken* by *Jane McGonigal*.  Not a short answer, but it is a great start.

Comment: Link to that book's site: http://realityisbroken.org/

Comment: Are your support agents volunteers or support is their responsibility?

Comment: Agents are not volunteers, they are paid agents.

Answer (score 1):

Anna,
You have to ask yourself the human question. "What's in it for me?" I think gamification would rock. But the agents need some way of doing something with it. Could the solution calculate to a pay raise during a review? It could but that would take to long and submissions would soon decline. A points based systems where the users can redeem those points for event tickets, movie tickets, or save them to go into a pool for a weekend get a way kind of thing would get people involved. This would also have to be backed up with internal corp communications to show case the event, the winning and/or the vacation that was one etc. There needs to be a buzz around the solution that's chosen.